# Should I ask contractors to install channel drain in front of my garage this way?

Tags: drainage

My garage floods halfway across the floor, under 1/2" of water, if it rains hard. This is what it usually looks like when it rains (there's a sewer drain near the fire hydrant to catch street water; not much flows down the driveway):

[image: Driveway]

So I'd like to put a channel drain in front of the garage that flows out into the retention pond:

[image: PathAlongGrass]

Note: The concrete ramp in front of the garage door (seen in second photo) is no longer there. The top photo is most recent. The ramp kinda works for light rain but it can trap water inside if it rains heavy.

Here's the front of the garage:

[image: FrontGarage]

And what the concrete floor (in front of the left garage door) currently looks like:

[image: Skirt]

And what the asphalt is like on the right side garage door:

[image: GarageRight]

And what I would like the contractors to do (5"x5" drain specs based on the profile of this [NDS Channel Drain](https://www.ndspro.com/5-pro-series-channel-drain-kit-with-metal-grate.html)):

[image: DrainPlan]

[image: DrainPlanFront]

I've spoken with some contractors so far and they want 5-7k for the job, which seems decent but on the high side for a drain. I estimated the material cost to be ~2k (concrete, rental, PVC pipe, and debris removal). Some guys told me it'd be a 1-3 day job. Some wanted to demo the skirt since it's in kind of rough shape. Others want to repoint it. I need to be sure I'm speaking to people who knows how to solve the problem.

I think the plan I have is a reasonable request but I don't know what the pitch is like from the right-to-left side of the house (along the green "y" axis). Ideally, it'd already be pitched 3" lower (1% grade over 26') on the left side of the garage so water flows in the direction of the pond. I mean, I know it slopes that way since that's the direction water currently flows but I'm unsure if the pitch is steep enough.

What do folks think about the complexity of this project?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Huesmann - It looks like the garage is lower than the drive, so rainwater will come down the drive.

Comment: Indeed, the garage is lower than street level. We also get water that leaks through the boulders of the retaining wall (behind it is a french drain, in front of the house). We're planning to get the retainer wall rebuilt but that is a bigger project for when we widen the driveway.

Comment: Is this not just a "shopping question" that refers back to the prices you contractors want to charge to do the work? The only other question asked seems to ask about opinions regarding the complexity of the job.

Comment: @RohitGupta looks in the 2nd pic like the driveway slopes away from the garage, towards the pond.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the channel in is the easy part, you can do that yourself.  I have done it myself, but I did get a Concrete guy to cut the channel.  This is because he cut it straighter than I would have.  I then dropped in the drain and bedded it in with mortar.

The slope of the drain itself (across the garage) is immaterial, the water will flow where it can get out.

Your problem is connecting the drain to your pond, and that needs to be done more professionally and the pipe/drain should have a fall.

I don't know rates in your area, but 7K sounds high.  If you don't have a contractor you can trust then get three quotes and go with the middle one.

Depending on the look you want, an open swale would be a lot cheaper.  A swale is a dished drain that is wider than a pipe would be (about 2ft wide by 4-6 inches deep in the middle) and will channel the water sway.  You just grass it like normal.  I am in a rural area and we do this all the time.

> What Is a Drainage Swale?
> Drainage is an essential component of a house. It prevents flooding, which can cause significant damage to your property. You can avoid flooding with different solutions for your yard, and a drainage swale is one of them.
>
> In the US, swales are shallow channels often covered with grass to look like a continuation of the house lawn. Their primary purpose is to collect and manage water flow by slowing the current and redirecting it to the desired destination.

From [What is a Drainage Swale](https://housenotebook.com/what-is-a-drainage-swale/).  I am not related to the website, I did struggle to find one in USA.

Comment: We have a swale on the other side of the retention pond that we'd like to fill/loam but that's a different (bigger) project. I don't think it'd be a good solution here since a swale doesn't look as good and it'd be positioned right at the opening to the backyard. That website is very informative though, thanks.

Comment: `The slope of the drain itself (across the garage) is immaterial, the water will flow where it can get out.` On youtube, I've seen a case where the channel was leveled at the center but higher on either end and water ended up "filling up" the channel drain and overflowing. Granted, this channel ran around a pool with a small 3"W drain, but in this case, if not properly sloped, it'd still work but it'd make the drain less effective at channeling water away.

Comment: `The slope of the drain itself (across the garage) is immaterial, the water will flow where it can get out.` But maybe I'm misinterpreting what you've written. Are you suggesting to run it level with the garage floor? I also think the floor has been sloped already, but I should check with a level to be certain. A 1% slope across 26' amounts to a 3" drop, which would look _really_ odd if the left side of the drain sat that much lower than the right. One solution here would be to make my own drain using concrete, using 6"D PVC pipe as a mould, and sloping the concrete 3" lower on the left side.